# Combining trim and if formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am using a trim formula in excel:

```
TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(M2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(M2,"-","|",2))+1,LEN(M2)),"-",REPT(" ",LEN(M2))),LEN(M2)))
```

this looks for a number in between a string of 4 numbers:

```
193449542-27309370502-9045796-169794419204
```

which works perfectly.

I want to add an if= when a another cell on that same row contains either "bing" or "Adwords" and skip cells that contain it.

Comment: Please create a table in the OP that shows your inputs and desired outputs.  It will help us understand.

Answer (score 4):

In H2 per the supplied image,

```
=IF(NOT(SUM(COUNTIF(J2, "*"&{"bing","Adwords"}&"*"))), TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(M2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(M2,"-","|",2))+1,LEN(M2)),"-",REPT(" ",LEN(M2))),LEN(M2))), "")
```

[image]

To add a condition where M2 must contain at least three hyphens, use `AND` and subtract the length of substituting the hyphens with "" (subtrahend) from the length of the original (minuend). If the result (difference) is 3 or more then there are at least three hyphens.

```
=IF(and((len(m2)-len(substitute(m2, "-", "")))>=3,NOT(SUM(COUNTIF(J2, "*"&{"bing","Adwords"}&"*")))), TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(M2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(M2,"-","|",2))+1,LEN(M2)),"-",REPT(" ",LEN(M2))),LEN(M2))), "")
```

Comment: awesome, that works, is there also a way to make sure it only does it when there's 4 sets of numbers (or at least 3 hyphens)
Thanks a bunch already!!

Comment: To check if there are three hyphens, subtract the length of substituting the hyphens with `""` (*subtrahend*) from the length of the original (*minuend*). If the result (*difference*) is 3 then there were three hyphens.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know what subtrahend means and how I would have to make the formula to get the result.

Comment: A simple google wil quickly define *subtrahend*; I've added the condition with some narrative above.

Comment: thanks a million!
I did need the cell to include bing or adwords but got rid of "not" and it worked