# Excel IF statement for trim function

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, street-address

Good afternoon,

I would like to have a fixed trim address, when it's possible.

My address is:

** 15-21 Bournemouth rd, Aberdeen, AB11 6YA**

I want to get rid of the postcode and keep the address form like this:

**15-21 Bournemouth rd, Aberdeen,**

In this event I have to use the TRIM function from the left, what I did.

I tried these 2 formulas:

```
 =LEFT(TRIM(D18),FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D18)&" "," ","^",4))-2)
```

and

```
 =TRIM(LEFT(D18, FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(D18, " ", "~",5)&"~")))
```

which gives me the results:

**15-21 Bournemouth rd, Aberdeen**

**15-21 Bournemouth rd, Aberdeen,**

then is fine. I am happy.

Although sometimes my address comes with the own name of the premise, like this:

**21-23 Regis House 15-21 Bournemouth rd, Aberdeen, AB11 6YA**

and then the issue becomes more complicated, as I cannot apply these formulas (I have to change them manually, which I don't want).

In the result of the same formula parameters I am getting accordingly:

**21-23 Regis House 15-2**

**23 Regis House, 15-21**

which is not good, as I need a full address without the postcode only.

I cannot change these formulas manually. On top of that, when I swap them to the right side, then the rightmost stuff is being kept.

I found something here:

[Combining trim and if formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907460/combining-trim-and-if-formula)

the IF statement for TRIM function, and net tried to plot it into my example:

```
   =IF(NOT(SUM(COUNTIF(A18, "*"&{",",","}&"*"))), TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A18,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A18,"-","|",2))+1,LEN(A18)),"-",REPT(" ",LEN(A18))),LEN(A18))), "")
```

which returns **#VALUE**.

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you can assume the post code will always be followed by the **last** comma, you can use that logic to extract your string

Comment: I knew the logic but i didn't know formula for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IF** we can assume your postcode **always** follows the last comma in your string you can use the below to extract everything before the last comma:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))))
```

*Note this also assumes that `@` will not be in your strings anywhere. We essentially want to replace your target comma with a symbol that will be unique to all other characters in any string*

---

### VBA

If you are open to VBA solution, you can use the below UDF to get the same results

```
Public Function LASTCOMMA(Target As String)

Dim i As Long, Arr
Arr = Split(Target, ",")

For i = LBound(Arr) To (UBound(Arr) - 1)
    LASTCOMMA = LASTCOMMA & Arr(i)
Next i

End Function
```