# Excel extract one word from the any part of the string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, street-address

I have the string containing the address, which sections are divided by commas.

**Outside Locksbrook Campus (Bath Spa University) Locksbrook Road, Bath, CB1 3QQ**  located in the D19 cell

I would like to extract the name of the city from this string, which is "Bath". The name of the city is always to be placed before the postcode.

I have managed with it in 2 steps. First I extracted everything before the last comma, like here:

[Excel IF statement for trim function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916476/excel-if-statement-for-trim-function)

```
  =MID(D19,1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(D19,",","@",LEN(D19)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D19,",","")))))
```

which gave me:

**Outside Locksbrook Campus (Bath Spa University) Locksbrook Road, Bath,**

and next, I had to extract the last word in my new string by using this formula:

```
  =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(AA5," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

which gave me pretty much the final result:

**Bath,**

However, I would like to make it done with 1 operation only.

Is it possible at all?

I found some formula here, which should have to extract any word (the nth word) from the string, but regrettably, it doesn't work in my case.

https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-nth-word-from-text-string

```
   =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(D19," ",REPT(" ",LEN(D19))), (N-1)*LEN(D19)+1, LEN(D19)))
```

it gives me `#NAME?` finally.

Moreover, I have misgivings, that it won't work, when the address string will be slightly different, containing more elements like block name, street name, city, postcode or only street name, city, and postcode.

Is there any way to extract only one section from the string before the last comma (after the pre ultimate comma)?

Comment: Just to bring out a possible edge case, would you ever expect the city to be more than one word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(D19,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()=last()-1]")
```

The xpath expression `//s[position()=last()-1]` tells the function to return the s-node that is second to last by position index.

For more information on `FILTERXML()` and the use of some xpath to return substrings of interest, you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) interesting.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I can now change from -1 to i.e. -2 and get the text "before" if I want :)

Comment: how about if I would like to extract two substrings instead of one. How your formula would look like?

Comment: @MKR, if you have a new question feel free to post another one on SO with some good sample data and your own attempt. Most likely you just want to extend the xpath-expression =)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
=MID(A2, SEARCH(",",A2) + 1, SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2)+1) - SEARCH(",",A2) - 1)
```

From here: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/01/split-text-string-excel/

Comment: Sorry to have downvoted, but this doesn't answer the question. What if there are more subsections in a comma-delimited string i.o.w. *more* commas. OP is only interested in the part between the 2nd-to-last and last comma as per his last two alineas. I'll definately undo the downvote if you can rectify this.

Comment: The Ablebits solution seems to be correct, although I am getting "Locksbrook Road" instead of "Bath", which is a text before. How can I amend the formula above?